# Hide layer from identify tool

Tags: qgis

I am new in qgis.

Do you know how hide selected layers from identify feature?

I select all the features because I need them to showed in the map. But when I used identify feature, I just want the one of them when identify feature pop up. (In this case, I don’t want ‘jateng’ show up in identify feature window).

Do you know how to hide it from identify features?

[image]

Comment: You are probably activating the pop-up menu by right-clicking of your mouse. If you left-click and set the Mode to `Current layer` then you will only see information of the selected layer.

Comment: @Kazuhito why don't you extend your comment and put it as an answer. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

From the look of your captured image, it seems you are activating the pop-up menu by right-clicking of your mouse.

After a little changes of your setting, please try to left-click at your desired point.

[image]

1. From `View` pull-down menu, click `Panels | Identify Results`. Then `Identify Results` window will appear.
2. Change `Mode` to `Current Layer`. Default setting would be `Top down, stop at first`.
3. Tick off `Auto open form`.

By selecting (highlighting) the layer of your interest in the Layers Panel, each left-click of your mouse button will immediately show you the information you need.

Note) Sorry my comment (above) "just left-click" was only relevant if you were using QGIS 2.14, but I noticed you are in QGIS 2.18.